# j2me NullPointerException adding image to a vector

Tags: image, java-me, vector, nullpointerexception

private Vector menuOptions;

```
void addOption(String imagefilename) {
    try {
        Image i = Image.createImage(imagefilename);
        menuOptions.addElement((Object)i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I'm getting:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GraphicMenu.addOption(GraphicMenu.java:31) //addElement line

Can I add a Inmutable images to a Vector Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you initialized the vector?

```
Vector menuOptions = new Vector();
```